# How to 'inject' data modal .ts to another

Tags: angular, angular7

Not sure if 'inject' is the right word. I'm still fairly new to coding, and I can ask my dad who is working along with me, but I wanted to try and make at stackoverflow question. Sorry if this ends up incomprehensible.

Background:

I am making a table of boards that have a popup dialog to add more boards to a proposal. The table pulls from 3 different data sets *proposal.ts , boards.ts , proposal-board.ts* The data is transferring fine, the trouble is getting it to display in the table.

The displayed data is tied up in `const proposalBoard = new ProposalBoard( ... )` with elements from proposal-board.ts, but the elements EndDate and StartDate are from proposal.ts, not proposal-board.ts.

**So the question is:** can I inject the elements EndDate and StartDate into proposal-board.ts? If so how?

---

edit-proposal.component.html

```
    <ng2-smart-table [settings]="proposalBoardSettings" [source]="proposal.Boards">
    </ng2-smart-table>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add-boards-modal"
        (click)="showBoardSelectDialog">+ Add Boards</button>

      <div *ngIf='proposal.Boards'>
        <app-boardselectdialog (selectedBoards)="addBoards($event)" [boards]="proposal.Boards"></app-boardselectdialog>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

edit-proposal.component.ts

```
export class EditProposalComponent implements OnInit {
 boards: any = {};
proposal: any = {};


proposalBoardSettings = {
    actions: false,
    columns: {
      StructureNumber: {
        title: 'StructureNum',
        filter: false
      },
      BoardName: {
        title: 'BoardName',
        filter: false
      },
      StartDate: {
        title: 'Start Date',
        filter: false
      },
      EndDate: {
        title: 'End Date',
        filter: false
      },
      Status: {
        title: 'Status',
        filter: false
      },
      Cost: {
        title: 'Cost',
        filter: false
      },
      Price: {
        title: 'Price',
        filter: false
      }
    }
  };

 addBoards(boards: any) {
    const newProposalBoards: ProposalBoard[] = [];
    boards.forEach(element => {
      // loops through the boards returned from the dialog
      // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
      console.log('Dialog Board', element);
      // creates new ProspoalBoards objects from Boards objects returned from Dialog
      const proposalBoard = new ProposalBoard(
        element.Name,
        element.StructureNumber,
        element.Cost,
        element.EndDate,   //<- these are squigled
        element.StartDate,  //<- these are squigled
      );
      // adds new ProposalBoards to the array
      newProposalBoards.push(proposalBoard);
    });
    console.log('ProposalBoards', newProposalBoards);
    // replace Boards with new array of boards to show on the table
    this.proposal.Boards = newProposalBoards;

    this.UpdateCosts();
    this.UpdatePrice();
    console.log('Proposals');
  }
}
```

---

proposal-board.ts

```
export class ProposalBoard {
         BoardName: string;
         StructureNumber: string;
         Cost: number;

         constructor(name: string, 
                    structureNumber: string, 
                    cost: number, 
                    ) {

          this.StructureNumber = structureNumber;
           this.BoardName = name;
           this.Cost = cost;
         }
       }
```

---

proposal.ts

```
export class Proposal {
    EndDate: string;
    StartDate: string;


    constructor(
        endDate: string,
        startDate: string,
    ) {
        this.EndDate = endDate;
        this.StartDate = startDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the table when you call the method of addBoards may help you